# SQL Server scope issue with Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

The following code is from a sproc in our ERP system:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[spGrantAFUserSelectPerm] 
iLoginName     varchar(255) = null,    
@iAppDB         varchar(255)= null,     
@iPLDB          varchar(255)= null,      
@retcode        int output                 

as 
   declare @TableName      varchar(255) 
   declare @TableCursor    varchar(255) 
   declare @ProcName       varchar(255) 
   declare @ProcCursor     varchar(255) 

   select @retcode = 1 

   if @iLoginName is null
           return @retcode 

   --AppDB 
   if @iAppDB is not null and @iAppDB <> ''
   begin
       select @TableCursor = 'select name from ' + @iAppDB + '..sysobjects where (type = ''U'' OR type = ''V'' OR type = ''TF'') AND uid = 1' 
       exec ('declare c_GrantAppTableAccess cursor for ' + @TableCursor + ' for READ ONLY') 
       open c_GrantAppTableAccess       
       fetch c_GrantAppTableAccess into @TableName 
       while @@fetch_status = 0 
       begin 
           exec ('use ' + @iAppDB + ' grant SELECT on ' + @TableName + ' to [' + @iLoginName + ']') 
               fetch c_GrantAppTableAccess into @TableName 
       end      
       close c_GrantAppTableAccess 
       deallocate c_GrantAppTableAccess 
   end
```

This code was working for years up until last week, when one of our developers was trying (unsuccessfuly) to deploy a CLR sproc.  Now, the sproc fails on line "open c_GrantAppTableAccess" with an error saying the cursor does not exist.  It is as if the cursor declaration is out of scope.  Any ideas?  Again, this was working for 5-7 years before last week.

Comment: Is the cursor not existing the only error that gets thrown?

Comment: Can you post the code of CLR sproc to know the side effect on the cursor.